# How do I clean my knit shoes?

Tags: cleaning, shoes, stain

So a couple months ago I got new shoes and they are white, they have all kinds a of stains on them, and I would like to clean them with out having to buy expensive cleaners. Does anyone know how to clean them?

Comment: It highly depends on what stained them. Maybe you can describe the stains or even post a picture of the shoes.

Comment: A picture would really help. I'm not sure what a knit shoe looks like.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove any sand or dirt from the soles
2. Take out any additional inlay soles (if there are any)
3. Put a dab of laundry detergent right onto the stains
4. Throw them into the washing machine (no additional detergents in the chamber or you risk excessive foaming)
5. Start a short low temperature program.

I have knit shoes, too, and washed them 3 times already. They can take quite a long time to dry completely (2 days in moderate weather with sunshine). You should **not** toss them into the dryer but let them air dry.

Once they are completely dry, add waterproofing spray to keep them clean just a little longer (they will stain again eventually...).

The only problem I have is that the soles of my shoes are made of a white rubber-like substance with print on them. The washing rubs off the print faster than the "normal" use of the shoes would have.

Comment: Note: most shoes and sneakers do not appreciate being tossed in a dryer. - Air- and sun-drying them is crucial.